# CSS not applying on ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I want the external CSS to be applied on ajax response.
 I am trying to create a page where after user selects options in a form and submits it then another form is loaded via ajax. But CSS is not applying on the ajax response. 
 *I could not figure out the mistake. Please correct me if the approach is not correct.*

```
$('#getStudents').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'feature1/getStudents.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#getStudents').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {
      //alert(returndata);            
      $("#listStudents").html(returndata);
    }
  });
});
```

**Here is the problem. On the 4th column css is not applying.** The check box should appear as ios switch (http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)

```
    <?php


    $output='';

    $output = $output. '
    <div class="panel panel-white">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <h3 class="panel-title"> Students </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="students" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> ID</th>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Attendance</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th> ID</th>
                        <th>Student ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Attendance</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>';
                $i=1;
                while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                    $output = $output. '<tr>
                        <td>'.$i++.'</td>
                        <td>'.$data["id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$data["id"].'</td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="ios-switch pull-right switch-md">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch pull-right fixed-header-check" checked>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>'; 
                }

    $output = $output. '
                </tbody>
            </table>  
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>'; 


    echo $output;  

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: Please show the html AND css in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOps..It isn't the css problem. It's javascript that caused the problem.

Actually, the switchery.min.js  appends a div with class switchery to . Because the script isn't initialised the rendering has failed.

Now adding the following javascript at the end of getStudents.php solved the issue.

```
    echo '<script language="javascript">
       if (Array.prototype.forEach) {
         var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".js-switch"));

         elems.forEach(function(html) {
           var switchery = new Switchery(html);
         });
        } else {
               var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".js-switch");

               for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                   var switchery = new Switchery(elems[i]);
                }
               }
          </script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because your html page where you include all the css are loaded as the document is ready..it reads all classes and according to the style sheet it applies on that.. but in ajax we load the other page on the same html page and this time browser not map the html classes to the style sheet that is why your css is not applying on that

Comment: OK.. understood. How do I acheive the required?

Comment: there iare two ways to do this one is inline css and other one is lode all the css files again after the ajax page is loded.. you can do it via jquey or java script

Comment: I used the following to reload the css. but it's not working. any ideas on how to it?
        function reloadStylesheets() {
            var queryString = '?v=' + new Date().getTime();
            $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function () {
                this.href = this.href.replace(/\?.*|$/, queryString);
            });
        }

I am using it inside ajax success block.

Comment: But I think CSS is applied by the browser to all elements that match the relevant selectors, whether added dynamically or not. Please correct me if I am wrong. I don't have to reload the css files in that case.

Comment: some times if the content (HTML content) is dynamic then it is not automatically updated.. i stuck in this type of problem previously.. but its a shot code so i added inline css.

Comment: In this case, I cannot add  inline css. So can you provide any wayarounds for my problem?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, did not understand what the guy's idea. Okay, the easiest way is to inline the CSS e.g. `<span style='color: here; .....'></span>`

Answer (score 0):

As I Can Understand , you are using an external JQuery Table Plugin and all the data (rows) are being fetched by AJAX Call.

You can use this setup[Backup your Previous File]:

What I am trying to do is:  fetching only the required rows in AJAX call(not complete table). All the table structures and CSS are already loaded and on form Submission trying to fetch required rows. In your case the browser doesn't able to dynamically render the Table and CSS.

**1. dashboard.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
          <!-- Link to Plugin CSS-->
          <!--Link to Your Custom CSS -->


     <head>
     <body>
            //HTML and PHP code  Here

       <!-- Link to Plugin Script-->
      <script>
        // AJAX CALL  
            $('#getStudents').submit(function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'feature1/getStudents.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: $('#getStudents').serialize(),
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(returndata) {
                  //alert(returndata);            
                  $("#students").html(returndata); //Fetch rows Only Not table(See the Next home.php page)
                  }
                }); 
               });

      </script>
     </body> 
</html>
```

**2. home.php**

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="panel panel-white">
       <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
          <h3 class="panel-title"> Students </h3>
       </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="table-responsive">
           <table id="students" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;"> 

            </table>
        </div>

       </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

**3. getStudents.php**

In this page Modify $output variable.

Like

```
 $output='';

$output = $output. '
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID</th>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Attendance</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID</th>
                    <th>Student ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Attendance</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>';
            $i=1;
            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                $output = $output. '<tr>
                    <td>'.$i++.'</td>
                    <td>'.$data["id"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$data["id"].'</td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="ios-switch pull-right switch-md">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch pull-right fixed-header-check" checked>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>'; 
            }

$output = $output. '
            </tbody></div>';
```